# Can i use AsyncLocal with azure function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am making use of Azure function and need to pass the HttpRequestMessage down the entire chain of async/await functions that are called. Can i instead use AsyncLocal in this case?

Shared Code:

```
public class ApiController
{
    public static AsyncLocal<HttpRequestContext> httpContext = new AsyncLocal<HttpRequestContext>();

    [FunctionName("api")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> RunAsync(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET", "POST", Route = "{requestType}/{source?}")]
        HttpRequestMessage req,
        string source,
        string requestType,
        TraceWriter logger)
    {
        HttpRequestContext requestContext = new HttpRequestContext(req, requestType, source);
        httpContext.Value = requestContext;
        return await RequestRouter.Dispatch();
    }
}
```

In the above code i want to access the httpContext inside Dispatch() as well. I am worried about what will happen with concurrency? Will the context change for this method in case a new request gets triggered?

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: Added some code snippet

Answer (score 0):

It should work. `AsyncLocal` will take care of preserving context between concurrent calls. I did a quick test and it was able to keep the request as expected.

Functions are generally small and simple, so I would default to easier ways to pass context through, usually just passing parameters around. But if `AsyncLocal` is relevant for your case, give a shot.

Comment: But what if some code is invoked by the Function SDK itself? (we just inject our implementation through setup of the Function host). In such a case, if I initialize AsynLocal in the function code - all subsequent threads will get NEW execution context and code , that is invoked by SDK, won't see the value in AsyncLocal (since it'll have different execution context). Any ideas how to overcome this? With .net framework I could access CallContext, but with .net standard it is not available. In asp.net that already implemented with IhttpContextAccessor, but how to do that for Azure Functions?